# WinRM error while connecting to raspberry pi through PowerShell on Windows 10

Tags: powershell, windows-10, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to connect to the raspberry pi 2 and change the device name through PowerShell. On entering the following command I get an error.

> Enter-PsSession -ComputerName XX.XX.XXX.177
>   -Credential XX.XX.XXX.177\Administrator

**Error:**

Enter-PsSession : Connecting to remote server XX.XX.XXX.177 failed with the
following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that th
specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the
network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and
allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception fo
public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local
subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PsSession -ComputerName XX.XX.XXX.177 -Credential XX.XX.XXX.177 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (XX.XX.XXX.177:String) [Enter-
   SSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed

ANy leads / help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I presume your Pi is running the Windows 10 IoT bits?

Comment: Did you set up PSRemoting? What did you do for troubleshooting?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf: Yes, I did setup the PSRemoting. tried changing ipAddress\Administraton to Administrator@ipAddress. Tried by disabling firewall as well. Nothing works as of now.

Comment: Does `Test-WSMan...` work?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf: It gives the following error "Unencrypted traffic is currently disabled in the client configuration."

Comment: @PeterHahndorf: I set the allowUnencyrpted as true, still the error continues

Comment: @saadasharif - You need to get that to work first. Google around for that problem. PSRemoting can be a bit tricky to set up.

Answer (score 1):

This Answer [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34053/powershell-cant-connect-to-windows-iot)  seems to do the trick without having to re-flash the SD Card

**ADDED BASED ON FEEDBACK**

The link essentially suggests that the user run the following commands when trying to establish the connection

```
net start WinRM
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value MINWINPC
remove-module psreadline -force
Enter-PsSession -ComputerName MINWINPC -Credential MINWINPC\Administrator
```

I believe the "magic" difference is the forced command:

```
remove-module psreadline -force
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: why did i get a down vote? my post actually fixes the problem. I just updated the answer to include the fix

Answer (score 0):

As per the recommendations in comments I tried various things. I did the PSRemoting setup

> Enable -PSRemoting -force

Finally, I removed the memory card from RaspberryPi formatted again and reinstalled Windows 10 IOT Core and then it worked perfectly fine. :)